# Where is the catkin_ws binaries?

Tags: ros, binaries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

is it possible to use just use  binaries(in another computer) of the catkin workspace after complied. If it is possible how and where are these Binaries ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277667/where-is-the-catkin_ws-binaries-?/) by [Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/32512/robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Robotics ,

when you run `catkin_make`, the generated files are normally in `~/catkin_ws/devel/`

If you run `catkin_make install`, they are normally on `~/catkin_ws/install/`.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/32512/robotics/) on 2017-12-10**:
thanks Ruben